# Display x/197 as text in a TextView with x changing each buttonclick

Tags: java, android, button

I have a textview where im trying to dispay this "1/197" and with a button click change it to 2/197 an so on..
this is my code..

```
public class playactivity extends Activity {
        public int counter = 1

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_jugar);

    Button nextbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    TextView numbertextview =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);


    numbertextview.setText(String.valueOf(counter));

 nextbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            TextView numbertextview =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);


                 @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                       // LO QUE HACE EL NEXT BUTTON
                    counter = counter + 1;
                    numbertextview.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
```

As you can see i already got my TextView to display "1" and with a buttonclick it changes to "2" and so on. Now i want to add this "/197" how do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just concatenate the "/197" to the number when you set the text:

```
numbertextview.setText(String.valueOf(counter) + "/197");
```

Comment: Oh wow, i feel stupid, that was really simple. Programming noob here. Thanks.

Comment: Don't feel stupid, everybody was a noob at some point. Don't forget to mark this as the answer if it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try this

```
numbertextview.setText(String.valueOf(counter)+"/197");
```